# openIMAJ missing class or wrong library

Tags: java, maven, xuggle, openimaj

I am doing [this](http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/processing-video.html) and I've encountered a problem.

Here's my code

```
package vid;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.openimaj.image.MBFImage;
import org.openimaj.video.Video;
import org.openimaj.video.xuggle.XuggleVideo;

public class Movie{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Video<MBFImage> video;
        video = new XuggleVideo(new File("in.flv"));

        for (MBFImage mbfImage : video) {
            //something
        }
        video.close();
    }   
}
```

and when I  run it I'm gettig

```
21:18:51.520 [main] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Could not open output url: file:/D:/Workspace/openIMAJ/in.flv (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:436)
1 [main] INFO org.openimaj.video.xuggle.XuggleVideo  - URL file:/D:/Workspace/openIMAJ/in.flv could not be opened by ffmpeg. Trying to open a stream to the URL instead.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openimaj/io/InputStreamObjectReader
at org.openimaj.video.xuggle.XuggleVideo$MBFImageConverter.toImage(XuggleVideo.java:264)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchVideoPicture(MediaReader.java:600)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeVideo(MediaReader.java:519)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:475)
at org.openimaj.video.xuggle.XuggleVideo.readFrame(XuggleVideo.java:482)
at org.openimaj.video.xuggle.XuggleVideo.hasNextFrame(XuggleVideo.java:577)
at org.openimaj.video.VideoIterator.hasNext(VideoIterator.java:59)
at vid.Movie.main(Movie.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openimaj.io.InputStreamObjectReader
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 8 more
```

And my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/vzXmqKZ4) (long, so I saved it on pastebin). There is a lot on dependencies to different parts of openIMAJ because I've lost track which does what. I've tried to download libs following [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20Library/), but when I add any other than core, I'm getting

```
Missing artifact org.openimaj:video:jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT
```

Libs provided on last site are different than those on Maven Central Repository.
So, my problem is, where can I find library (or which one from MCR could help) with desired class?  Or libs compatible with tutorials on openIMAJ site.

Thank for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you define `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`? Such not using Maven's widely accepted default [`${project.basedir}/src/main/java`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM).

The [OpenIMAJ Wiki page](https://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20Library/)'s latest update is from [Sep 2012](https://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20Library/history). I'd go with the [latest release version 1.3.1 from Sep 2014 on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|openimaj).

If you really want to use snapshots: version 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT of `core` is from 2013. There is a [1.4-SNAPSHOT](http://maven.ecs.soton.ac.uk/content/repositories/openimaj-snapshots/org/openimaj/core/) which is just about one month old. This probably applies to [other `core-...` libs](http://maven.ecs.soton.ac.uk/content/repositories/openimaj-snapshots/org/openimaj/) as well. I recommend to use the latest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later and see if it works. About <sourceDirectory>, pom wast generated in Eclipse and I didn't ever need to change it, but thaks